# How to use window onload in a single page application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm using `node.js` in order to build a single page application.

At the top of the homepage I used a `100vh css style` to show some color in full screen, and then after page loads, I created a `transition` to load an image.

I used this code:

**JS**

```
$('body').addClass('is-loading');
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('body').removeClass('is-loading');
});
```

However, `single page application` doesn´t need to load again after it loads. So, my question is how can I achieve this transition using *node.js*? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Window onload** would works fine in a static web page. In a single page application you can use `setTimeout` (as one possible solution) to `removeClass`.

For what I understand you want transition works any time in your app:

This code works fine (is already tested):

```
if ( ! $('body').is('.is-loading') ) {
  $('body').addClass('is-loading');
}

setTimeout(function () {
  $('body').removeClass('is-loading');
}, 1000)
```

I hope it works in your code. Would be great to see some example of your css code. For now, you can achieve transition with the example written above.

Change time parameter according to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use localStorage.

Using a native js approach

```
localStorage.setItem('myToggle', isLoaded);
```

and then you retrieve from the same local storage using getItem and then specifying the name of the created localStorage item.

```
var isItAlreadyLoaded = localStorage.getItem('myToggle');
```

So

```
window.onload = function(){
  var isItAlreadyLoaded = localStorage.getItem('myToggle');
  if(isItAlreadyLoaded == 'true'){
    console.log('already loaded');
  }
  else{
    //load image here
    //.....

    var isLoaded = 'true';
    localStorage.setItem('myToggle', isLoaded);
    console.log('saved!');
  }
}
```

This works like magic. localStorage is some sort of browser mini-storage, each storage variable can hold upto 5~10mb depending on the browser. It works well in most modern browsers.

All I did was put a boolean variable to check if the image was already loaded, or just check for the existence of the localStorage.